# Проблемы с кодировкой при скачивании html с помощью requests

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, кодировка, requests

Пытаюсь спарсить страницу http://mezgil.kz/. Python 3. Получаю кракозябры типо таких:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код ниже, скрипт сохранен в utf-8. Я не знаю что может быть не так, ведь другие сайты норм парсятся:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests

result = requests.get('http://mezgil.kz', timeout=30.0)
page = result.text
print(page)
```

Comment: А другую кодировку попробовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```python
import requests

result = requests.get('http://mezgil.kz', timeout=30.0)
result.encoding='utf-8'
page = result.text
print(page)
```

Документация - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: @baurzhan отображается в print как на сайте

Answer (score 3):

`requests` неверно кодировку ответа определил. Для `r.text` использовалась `iso-8859-1` вместо правильной в этом  случае `utf-8`, поэтому кракозябры напечатались.

Сервер не указал кодировку в `Content-Type` http заголовке, поэтому `requests` выбрал кодировку по умолчанию для http `iso-8859-1` (бесполезный и часто вредный выбор, основанный на устаревшей RFC 2616), не пытаясь посмотреть на html-содержимое ответа, в котором прописана другая кодировка `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Разработчики объясняют это тем, что `requests` это http библиотека, а не html библиотека.

Правила как именно кодировка должна быть указана (указывать ли в разных местах (как в Content-Type заголовке так и в html документе или только в html документе), что имеет приоритет, BOM, какая кодировка по умолчанию) менялись со временем. Сейчас html5 просто utf-8 требует: ["The Encoding standard requires use of the UTF-8 character encoding"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#charset). См. [Require UTF-8](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/fae77e3c558b9f083dfb9086752863a4789268f5). Поэтому можно жёстко прописать:

```
response.encoding = 'utf-8'
print(response.text)
```

Если сайт использует какую-то другую кодировку, не указанную в http заголовке, то практичная опция это использование [`BeautifulSoup` класса](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings), специализированного для работы с html и который может поддерживать даже случаи когда [документ представлен из смеси кодировок](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#inconsistent-encodings). См. [A good way to get the charset/encoding of an HTTP response in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14592762/4279).

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще один очень неплохой вариант получить байты напрямую и уже их расшифровывать, например:

```python
data = requests.get(url)
text = data.content.decode('UTF-8')
```